# Amazon S3 huge file integrity

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very confused regarding how can I check the integrity of the files I upload to Amazon S3. I can see some StackOverflow questions about that, but they seem to use older APIs, which look very different from what I'm using now, and they refer to the E-Tag containing the md5, which seems to not be valid anymore, or for files over 5GB.

So, basically, I'm using PHP to upload huge files (some of them over 70GB), using MultipartUploader with a Try/Catch like this:

```
        try {
            $result = $uploader->upload();
        } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
            $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3, $file, array(
                'state' => $e->getState()
            ));
        }
```

I get several errors like these:

> An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload. The following parts had errors:
>   - Part 7729: Error executing "UploadPart" on ... resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
>   
>   `InternalError`We encountered an internal error. Pleas (truncated...)
>    InternalError (server): We encountered an internal error. Please try again. - 
>   `InternalError`We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
>
> Part 660: Error executing "UploadPart" on "..."; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  (server): 100 Continue -
>
> Part 6542: Error executing "UploadPart" on "..."; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

All of these seem to fall into the Catch of "MultipartUploadException", which tries to upload again from the current state.

But I'm still concerned about the integrity of the files uploaded, so I'd like to know how to check that. When I look in the S3 Management Console, the properties of one file says:

> ETag: ba66d1235f954f28366ddc0a7efcb295-1609

But when I do "md5sum" locally, I get something totally different:

> fa693af7341c6c83e525ebc6b95422ea

Does this mean the uploaded file is corrupted?

If not, what is the way to check the integrity of the uploaded files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On multipart uploads, the etag is computed by taking the binary encoding¹ of each part's md5 hash, concatenating them together, doing an md5 of that, hex-encoding the result, then appending the `-` followed by the number of parts.

If you know the upload part size, you can calculate the correct multipart etag value for a given file.  I wrote an s3 multipart uploader (unreleased) that pre-calculates this value and stores it as `x-amz-meta-expect-etag` for later manual or machine validation.  Somewhere, I may have a standalone utility that calculates this from local files after the fact.  I'll look for it.

You are correct to be cautious but your concerns may be largely unfounded.  If the library you are using takes advantage of the failsafes built in to the multipart API, you should be good:

Each part, when uploaded, should send a `Content-MD5` header, containing the base64 encoding of the md5 hash of that part.  If this is present in the request, S3 will deliberately fail to accept that part, since the data is considered to have been corrupted in transport.

Each part, when uploaded, receives a response that includes the etag for that part, containing the md5 of the part, in hex.  The code should be verifying that value.

S3 then requires you to assemble the "complete" request to finalize the upload when all the parts are done. In this request, you include all the etags of the individual parts, which you are supposed to maintain locally while the upload is in progress.  (There's a way to interrogate S3 for the list, but that's for cross-checking, and that data shouldn't be used to actually assemble the complete-multipart-upload request.  If these values are not as S3 thinks they should be, the request fails and the object never exists in the bucket.

So, done properly, S3 multipart upload is quite good at assuring data integrity... it tries very hard not to let you get it wrong and create imperfect objects.  You should audit the code of the libraries you're using to verify that they do these things.  If they do, you should be good.  In an early version of internal system so wrote, I actually used `curl 'https://{pre-signed-url}' | md5sum` after each multipart upload to verify. It ran this way for a couple of years and I literally *never* managed to create a bad multipart upload, when using all and-written code to talk directly to the S3 service (no SDK) using the safeguards provided by the multipart API.

---

¹an md5 hash is a 128 bit value.  Its "binary encoding" (not a precise term, since it's not really "encoded," just "raw") is a 16 byte value, where each byte contains a valued in the range of 0-255.  If the bytes of an md5 hash are simply cast as a string, many of the bytes result in unprintable characters... so, the common representation is in hex, which results in 32 bytes (128 ÷ 4) of output (using characters 0-9, a-f) because each hex character only encodes 4 bits... or somewhat less commonly in base64 (characters 0-9A-Za-z+/=) where you get 24 bytes (128 ÷ 6, rounded up to the next multiple of 4) of output because each character encodes 6 bits.  You don't concatenate the 32-byte hex-encodings, you need the raw binary version of the md5 of each part, each of which is 16 bytes.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your answer. It's a shame they don't provide the full MD5 sum for the whole file. It would be overkill to split my files in parts and calculate the MD5 sum for each of them... However, I've just downloaded 2 of the largest files, calculated MD5 and it matched the local sum. Very kind regards and thank you for your time in replying.

Comment: Creating a checksum is CPU-intensive. If you've tried to calculate the checksum of a 20 GB video file, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading to S3, the only way to guarantee copy fidelity (perfect transfer) is to use checksums. In order to make this manageable, AWS allows you to break up your file into parts, calculate the checksum and then send that checksum as part of your signature AND in the "Content-Md5" header.

It is not true that you can assume that what you post to S3 is stored without error.

It is not rare that AWS PUT API requests return 500 or other errors. This is documented and one of the reasons why AWS requires that you simply try again in such cases.

The enormous benefits of AWS S3 multipart uploads are primarily copy fidelity, upload recovery incase of error (you only have to retry the part, not the whole file) and, if you've got a very fat pipe, parallelization of uploads for improved throughput.

There is a very popular browser-based implementation with all the above at https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS because the AWS JavaScript SDK for browsers has not supported checksums in multipart uploads for anything but text mime types (nothing binary like video, image, music).